What matter modeling problems could be solved with 100 error-corrected qubits?
IBM, Infleqtion, QuEra, and other quantum hardware companies have announced roadmaps where they expect to have 100 or more error-corrected qubits by the end of the decade. It seems increasingly likely that at least one of them will succeed.
What sorts of non-trivial matter modeling problems could be studied with 100 error-corrected qubits?
The answer(s) I'm looking for are (ideally) papers that have made a fairly specific claim in this regard (e.g. with our algorithm, you could understand this specific chemical reaction if you had 100 fault-tolerant* qubits) with fairly detailed resource estimates.
*Note: I'm aware fault tolerant and error corrected don't mean exactly the same thing, but that's not the point of this question.
Edit: I've posted an expanded version of this question over on the quantum computing stack exchange.
